# What web framework uses "javascript:__doPostBack()"

Tags: javascript

I've seen this all over the web

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnk2','')
```

Checking headers of the last place I saw it didn't reveal a server side language.

What server side language and/or framework encourages this style of link?

Comment: Ugly as hell, isn't it? ASP.NET can sure generate some crappy HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET server controls that post to the current page generate those kind of links.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft's ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's Asp.net Web forms frameworks uses this type of convention to make post back to page.